# Two different definite integrals having same Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The rieman sum of the expression
$\frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (10+\frac{3i}{n})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the definite integral $\int_{10}^{13}x^{\frac{1}{2}}dx$ but the question asks me about another integral which has the same rieman sum as the one above. The other integral is of the form $\int_6^9 f(x)\,dx$

I tried working out the other integral and it's $\int_6^9 (10+x)^{1/2}\,dx$ but this is clearly wrong after evaluating the integral.

Any hints on this question.

Comment: Take $f(x)=(x+4)^{1/2}$

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy , how did you get this expression ?

Comment: He did a change of variable of the form $u=x \pm a$ to shift the interval.

Comment: @N.S Thanks, I get it now.